# Yii2 validate username

Tags: php, validation, yii2

In my Yii2 application i'm trying to validate a field that i use for the username input using a custom validation method that check if this field have blank spaces.

```
class SomeModel extends Model
{
  public $username;
  public $email;
  public $password;

  public function rules()
  {
    return 
    [
       // Other rules
     [
            [
                'username',
                'password',
            ],
            function ($attribute, $params)
            {
                if (preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $this->attribute)) {
                     $this->addError($attribute, 'No white spaces allowed!');
                }

            },
        ],
    ],
  }
```

The problem that is not working. Records are saving with some blank spaces.

In the view this is the field:

```
  <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'placeholder' => 'Username'])->label(FALSE); ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried [filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#filter)

Comment: change `user_username`  to `username` like `<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'placeholder' => 'Username'])->label(FALSE); ?>`

Comment: you want to throw an error when the username or password contains blank spaces ? Or you want to replace the white spaces?

Comment: @wishu...ehm sorry yes it was username in that form field (i've copied wrong). M. I  I'd like to trow an error

Comment: @giovaZ then you should use preg_match('/\s+/',$this->attribute). preg_replace just does the replacement and returns the string with replaced characters and if('string') will always return false.

Comment: try [match](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#match)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class SomeModel extends Model
{
  public $username;
  public $email;
  public $password;

  public function rules()
  {
    return 
    [
       // Other rules
     [
            [
                'username',
                'password',
            ],
            function ($attribute, $params)
            {
                //returns true / false (preg_replace returns the string with replaced matched regex)
                if (preg_match('/\s+/',$this->attribute)) {
                     $this->addError($attribute, 'No white spaces allowed!');
                }

            },
        ],
    ],
  }
```

Comment: The method is right, but i don't think it's the way i write the validation. I've tried other methods like 'filter', with your function and to edit the other rules where the field 'username' appeared. I'm sure that i'm doing the operations in the username field (i've posted the portion of the code in my view). But i don't know why it doesn't validate.

Comment: do you have any frontend validation ?

Comment: Also, can you show how are you using the validate method ?

Comment: I've seen in my code a field that caused trouble with this valdiation method,  i've signed your answer as correct